# How do I generate a public and private key pair with these parameters in ECC?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Parameters for ECC [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NflM.png)

I want to generate a key pair with these parameters. I am unable to understand this. How do I generate one?

Comment: See the algorithm/process using the companion specification to the secp256k1 : SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field you show: http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf. You can also use tools such as https://8gwifi.org/ecfunctions.jsp (there are similar ones out there) or you can use OpenSSL to do it.

Comment: @Moo I am not looking for application, I want to do it raw using a pen paper and a calculator. If you can teach me it would be great

Comment: You cannot do it by hand for examples this large, you can create much smaller examples and then do it by hand. The spec shows the algorithm and process - it is a very short section.

Comment: @Moo How do I create smaller examples with ECIES scheme? Can you please answer this with an example? it would help a lot.